# Android app: Why does it timeout on multiple http post

Tags: android, api, timeout, http-post

I updated my Nexus 5 to Lollipop and now my Android App got this bug:

My App get it's content from my websites api. For this purpose the app contacts the API "Sync", which responses a List of Items that are new or updated. The app reads this List, loops through the different Items and starts a `httppost` in a AsyncTask to load the content from the API for each Item.
For beeing able to cancel the update process, I only start the next `httppost` when the previous is completed.

On lower Android versions there is no problem, but with Lollipop when I start the update the first 4 Items are loaded normally (and fast: 50ms) but the fifth stucks during `response = httpClient.execute(httppost);` in the following Code:

```
    HttpPost httppost;
    try {
        httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(Globals.TAG_API, "Wrong URL");
        throw e;
    }
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParams, false);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    HttpEntity entity;
    try {
        Log.d(Globals.TAG,"Start");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
        response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d(Globals.TAG,"Stop");
        entity = response.getEntity();
    }
```

After 30 seconds the Timeout cancels the Connection. **Also important:** during this 30 seconds the whole Homepage is not reachable anymore. I don't think the bug is in the API, because devices with an older version of Android are using the same API...

Please comment, if you need more Code from the API or the APP, I just hope the bug is in the Code above :)

**Update 21.12.2014**
After a little discussion in the comments, we have found that, that a `sleep(300)` inside the AsyncTask (in which is the `httppost`) solves the problem. So the problem was, that too many httppost reached the server and blocked my ip, with the `sleep` this is reduces ;-)

**Update 1.1.2015**
I did not found if the problem is server-based or in my app. But now I use GoogleVolley for my API and it works awesome!

Comment: `For beeing able to cancel the update process, I only start the next httppost when the previous is completed.` How are you doing that in combination with `loops through the different Items` ?

Comment: From my **Sync-API** I get a List with IDs (called `todoList`) that I store in my Update-Class. Then I start my function `doUpdate` that takes the next item of the `todoList` and starts an AsyncTask with the current item's ID, that contacts my API. When the AsyncTask is done and successful and the cancel button was not clicked, I call that function `doUpdate` again.

Comment: Ok. That's ok. When my internet server gets too many connections in a certain time he will block further connections for the offending ip for a time. I added a sleep before each new http call. Just add a sleep(1000) for a quick test to see if it helps.

Comment: That works, thank you so far! So do you think it's the fault of my internet server? May I change this somerwhere in the servers configuration or does my app has to sleep a specific time? My server is from www.all-inkl.com

Comment: It is no fault but intended behaviour. The webmaster can mostly adjust this security setting.

Comment: That sounds great, thank you! I just wonder, why my Homepage only blocks the newer Versions of Android. Does it maybe send httpposts faster?

Answer (score 0):

read the docs on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) 'threadpoolexecutor'

try to determine whether the platform API upgrade shifted in some way the default strategy for the pool and the number of threads and the executor employed by your asyncTask??

If you want alternate way of controlling your own client side pooled http executors, [look here](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/) for example of running your own framework for for async http queues using android handlers.